# Embed files to an illustrator project

Tags: adobe-illustrator, embed, file-placing

I dragged and drop some PSD files into a project in Illustrator CS5.
I want to remove them from my desktop, but if I do that, then they will disappear from my project.

What can I do in my project **now** (already opened with these files), to copy all current PSDs from desktop so I can delete them from my desktop ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more, as it is your question is difficult to understand and may get downvoted/closed.

Comment: Thanks you are very kind. When you copy a photo to illustrator by draging it, he will only copy a reference. If I then remove this file from my desktop, illustrator will not be able to find that art again. How can I tell it to COPY this and not just link to it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to *embed* the file to your project, rather than linking it.

That can be done by

Selecting the file in the Links panel (*Window→Links*), and choosing *Embed Image* from the dropdown menu.

[image]

<sub>Note, that embedding the images can (and most likely significantly) increase your artwork size.</sub>

[Read more about embedding and linking on Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/importing-artwork-files.html)

Comment: Do i have to do this for every copy of every image on this artwork ?

Comment: @curnelious you can select all the images in the links panel and do it to all of them at once.